# objective-c formatting

Tags: support, markdown

When I put objective-c code into stackoverflow (with the code tags)
It will displayed almost without any readable format.

Comment: How are you formatting the code sections? Do you precede each line with 4 spaces or use the "code" icon (101010) to format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code-tag:**

## import

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(int) numerator;
-(int) denominator;
@end

**versus**

**4 spaces indentation:**

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(int) numerator;
-(int) denominator;
@end
```